# Printing contents of array on separate lines

Tags: php, arrays

Experimenting with arrays and wondering why the following DOESN'T seem to print the values on SEPARATE lines when I run it?

```
<?php

$my_array = array("stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3");

echo $my_array[0] . "\n";
echo $my_array[1] . "\n";
echo $my_array[2] . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: [It doesn't?](http://codepad.org/ODwBGpcs)?

Comment: Note, `<br>` is a literal element line break. But, if you have a wrapping context which is a whitespace context, `<br>` and `\n` (or `\r\n`) is probably not all that different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my PHP textbook:

> One mistake often made by new php programmers (especially those from a
>   C background) is  to try to break lines of text in their browsers by
>   putting end-of-line characters (“\n”) in the  strings they print. To
>   understand why this doesn’t work, you have to distinguish the output
>   of  php (which is usually HTML code, ready to be sent over the
>   Internet to a browser program)  from the way that output is rendered
>   by the user’s browser. Most browser programs will  make their own
>   choices about how to split up lines in HTML text, unless you force a
>   line  break with the `<BR>` tag. End-of-line characters in strings will
>   put line breaks in the HTML  source that php sends to your user’s
>   browser (which can still be useful for creating readable  HTML
>   source), but they will usually have no effect on the way that text
>   looks in a Web page.

The `<br>` tag is interpreted correctly by all browsers, whereas the `\n` will generally only affect the source code and make it more readable.

Comment: Not really. You were alright until you got into the `\n` vs `<br>` argument. A `<pre>` block makes much of this beside the point. Just depends on where you come into that flow.

Comment: So is that last part about the `\n` affecting source code wrong?  Or is it just that whether or not the `\n` gets picked up depends on the tag it's enclosed in?

Comment: WTF, I don't even know. How's that for an answer?

Comment: Hopefully you understand, but I should probably be looking at this tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

This makes the trick.

```
<?php
    $my_array = array("stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3");
    foreach ( $my_array as $item ) {
        echo $item . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This could be written `echo "$item<br />";`

Answer (score 3):

If your viewing the output in a web browser, [newlines aren't represented visually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n).  Instead you can use HTML breaks:

```
<?php
    $my_array = array("stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3");
    echo implode('<br>', $my_array);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code block! Although it _might_ answer the question, it is not much good without explanation. Could you include some explanation with your answer. From Review.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print with `<br/>` instead of `\n` because the default PHP mime type is HTML, and you use `<br/>` to accomplish line breaks in HTML.

For example,

```
<?php

$my_array = array("stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3");

echo $my_array[0] . "<br/>";
echo $my_array[1] . "<br/>";
echo $my_array[2] . "<br/>";

?>
```

Comment: If you're using HTML5, the closing tag is not necessary.

Comment: The closing tag is a requirement of XHTML, not HTML. Version notwithstanding.

Answer (score -1):

That's because in HTML a line break is `<br />`, not `"\n"`.

Comment: Totally dependent on the *display* intent, thus a `pre` block would show both, but `\n` is probably not the "same".