# Line break in HTML with '\n'

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Is there a way to make HTML properly treat `\n` line breaks? Or do I have to replace them with `<br/>`?

```html
<div class="text">
  abc
  def
  ghi
</div>
```

Answer (score 957, accepted):

This is to show new line and return carriage in HTML. Then you don't need to do it explicitly. You can do it in CSS by setting the white-space attribute pre-line value.

```html
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.CommentText</span>
```

Comment: You can also use `white-space: pre-wrap` if want to retain tabs space also.

Comment: Great answer! the problem with answers with `<pre>` is the block is rendered like a code block

Comment: I might be missing something but this just doesn't seem to work.
`<span style="white-space: pre-line">Does this work? \n No</span>`

Comment: @JKL You can't put \n in there; it has to be an actual newline.

Answer (score 376):

You can use CSS `white-space` property for `\n`. You can also preserve the tabs as in `\t`.

For line break `\n`:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

For line break `\n` and tabs `\t`:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

```js
document.getElementById('just-line-break').innerHTML = 'Testing 1\nTesting 2\n\tNo tab';

document.getElementById('line-break-and-tab').innerHTML = 'Testing 1\nTesting 2\n\tWith tab';
```

```css
#just-line-break {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

#line-break-and-tab {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="just-line-break"></div>

<br/>

<div id="line-break-and-tab"></div>
```

Comment: This is available for a long time and it's [supported by all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: It is important to note that for this to work, your `\n` needs to be registered as HTML. If it just comes in as pure text, it will be displayed as text.

Answer (score 101):

It can be done various ways.

For example, if you want to insert a new line in a text area, you can use these:

`&#10;` line feed and `&#13;` carriage return, used like this:

```html
<textarea>Hello &#10;&#13;Stackoverflow</textarea>
```

You can also use `<pre>---</pre>` preformatted text like this:

```html
<pre>
  This is line 1
  This is line 2
  This is line 3
</pre>
```

Or you can use a `<p>----</p>` paragraph tag like this:

```html
<p>This is line 1</p>
<p>This is line 2</p>
<p>This is line 3</p>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last note? I don't understand why you think server side support is required for this...

Comment: The last sentence here is objectively false, as several other answers have demonstrated. And even if it weren't supported natively, you could easily change it with client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 39):

You could use the `<pre>` tag

```html
<div class="text">
<pre>
  abc
  def
  ghi
</pre>
  abc
  def
  ghi
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

Using `white-space: pre-line` allows you to input the text directly in the HTML with line breaks without having to use `\n`

If you use the **`innerText`** property of the element via JavaScript on a non-pre element e.g. a `<div>`, the `\n` values will be replaced with `<br>` in the DOM by default

- `innerText`: replaces `\n` with `<br>`
- `innerHTML`, `textContent`: require the use of styling `white-space`

It depends on how your applying the text, but there are a number of options

```
const node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerText = '\n Test \n One '
```

Comment: Interesting.  I ran into this on accident.  Is there any documentation describing this?

Comment: There's a number of different concepts here, and the `br` behavior is browser dependent - so it's unlikely to be described as a single piece of documentation. I've rarely used `innerText`, but use `white-space` styling regularly

Answer (score 26):

You can use this CSS property:

```css
white-space: pre-line
```

Comment: THANK YOU! -- been looking at this for a couple of days now - and it works great.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `<pre>` tag:

```html
<div class="text">
<pre>
abc
def
ghi
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Simple and linear:

```
 <p> my phrase is this..<br>
 the other line is this<br>
 the end is this other phrase..
 </p>
```

Comment: The <br> HTML element produces a line break in text (carriage-return). It is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of lines is significant. This is easier. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: @DiegoLopeLoyola I agree with you but sometimes some compilers or programming languages unfortunately accepts only this HTML tag for this purpose.

Answer (score 11):

You can use any of the following CSS,

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

or

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

or

```
white-space: break-spaces;
```

For more info read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 3):

A simple and more natural solution that doesn't involve CSS styles or numeric character references like `&#13;&#10;` would be to use the `&NewLine;` character entity reference:

```
The primary colors are:&NewLine;- Red&NewLine;- Green&NewLine;- Blue
```

---

**Note**: Since this is defined simply as the LF (line feed, or the `U+000A` Unicode code point) character, it can be debatable whether it suits scenarios where the entire CR + LF (carriage return + line feed) sequence is required. But then, it worked in my Chrome, Edge and WebView2 tests done in Windows 10, so it should be safe to use.

Comment: This worked but required CSS `white-space: pre-line;`. Both work well together since some code formatters remove white space.

Comment: What is the intent of `&NewLine;`? Literal? Rendered somehow? Some kind of encoding of non-printable ASCII character? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's just the character entity reference of a line feed, similar to how `&#10;` from the accepted answer is its numerical (decimal) entity reference in XML / HTML. They are standard textual or numerical representations of a character defined in the [HTML specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references) and can be used for almost all Unicode characters, irrespective if they are printable or not. It's not specially rendered, it's just one of the three ways (literal, numerical, textual) to represent such an "entity" in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` or `\t` or `\r` are interpreted inside of `<pre>---</pre>`

It worked for me.