# Why escape code \n, \r in JSON doesn't work?

Tags: html, json, angular

I know I am revisiting an old problem but I hope there are new answers. I am using angular/Modal to display a paragraph from a .json file. I need to insert a newline for each paragraph when displayed in the browser. I have tried \n ,\r, 
 This is a sample of an entry:

```
"termsAndServiceContent": "1. TERMS OF USE: \n These Terms of Use (Terms) govern your access or use, from within the United States and its territories and possessions ...........\r <br/>   By accessing or using the Services, you confirm your agreement to be bound by these Terms........",
```

I expected to get a new line for the \n and \r but nothing happens. How can I get the browser to recognize the escape characters?

I guess the question is quite similar and I did mentioned that its an old issue. I really didn't see this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n
```

question before but I still don't believe the answers address my issue. I am not using plain HTML I am using Angular and my render code looks like this:

```
<a (click)="showTermAndServicesWindow($event)">{{LOCALIZATION.tos}}</a>
```

where .tos is my .json file and that's all the HTML I want in the view....also I don't want to do any HTML templating in the .ts modules.

Comment: you'll have to replace it with html. html ignores a lot of whitespace.

Comment: You need to use HTML if you want the browser to interpret linebreaks such as `<br>`

Comment: In a web browser, HTML is displayed. It is a markup and has its own marker for newlines (<br>). The escaped control characters (\r \n) are for not for browsers

Comment: @marekful ....I get it that \n\r are not for browsers and I should use <br>. My problem is I just want to insert <br> in the .json text. something like this ....<a>text from .json file<br/> this doesn't work<a/>  When I do this the browser doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML code `<br>` for new lines, and make sure you use `<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>` to insert it as HTML.

Comment: your answer is not clear...I don't intend to mess with my .html or .ts files so where should i insert these changes?

Comment: @MichaelE you have to use the `innerHTML` binding to insert HTML into an Angular template. It's HTML because you can't use `\n` to insert line breaks. If you're looking for a different approach. You'll need to ask a different question.