# Multiple lines on p:treeNode

Tags: primefaces, treenode

I've created a DefaultTreeNode with primefaces.It works alright but I'd like to have 2 lines on each node instead of one.Is it possible to do that.
Here's what I've tried so far :

> TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0" +"\n" +" 2nd line",
>   root);

and

> TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0" +"\r\n" +" 2nd line",
>   root);

but none of them work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you check if the default CSS style rules for tree nodes wrap new lines?

Comment: How would you do this in plain html? Within a div....

Comment: @Kukeltje do you mean using `<br/>`? Wouldn't that be escaped when the node is rendered?

Comment: @JasperdeVries: No, I mean having a `<div>Bla\nBla</div>` in plain html and then have that display an actual new line. Lots of questions on that in StackOverflow...

Comment: @Kukeltje OK. I was also referring to that in my comment. I now spent more time commenting than it would take to find the duplicate... So here it is:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in html with \`\n\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: hahaha... I missed your initial comment, Think it crossed mine... Hoped the OP would look for it. Too often they post something and vanish for more than a couple of days... Very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

With `h:panelGrid` you can define the lines that you consider inside.
You can also use it for columns.

```
<p:treeNode> 
    <h:panelGrid  columns="1"   cellpadding="1" columnClasses="label,value" >
        <p:column style="width:10%"> 
            <img src="#{node.t01IdT03.t03Icono}"  height="20" width="20"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:10%"> 
            <img src="#{node.t01IdT02.t02Icono}"  height="20" width="20"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.t01NombreSitio}" />
        </p:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:treeNode>
```