# How do I style a "\n" using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to style a \newline using css only-- in my text I have entries like this:

"Hello, this is the text and \nthere's more text hereasdf adf \nmore text here"

which should render like this:

> Hello, this is the text and
>
> there's more text here asdf adf
>
> more text here

How do I change the styling of the escaped \newline using css (i.e. make the height 20px)? Can I do that since the \n isn't an html element?

Not the same as [Line break in html with `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n) because I don't have a problem getting the \n in my document.  I just want to change how it's displayed.

Comment: You cannot style the return but this sounds like a case for using `line-height` property.

Comment: you can use <br> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't target specific characters in content.

You can target an element and make new line characters significant with [the `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and you can change [the `line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, this is the text and
there's more text here asdf adf
more text here</p>
```

Comment: Marking as correct because answered my question, there is no way to style the \n.  The solution I ended up using was adding <hr> which I could then style how i wanted.