# Pretty print for JSON in Java works fine for the console, but in browser it does not work

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON file and I want to retrieve its content from a API call within a rest controller created in Java Spring Boot.
I get the content of the .json file into a String and use the below method ( one of them ) in order to pretty print.
If I system.out.println() the output, it gets pretty printed, but in the browser it is displayed roughly and with no indentation. I had more approaches :

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(content);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
System.out.println(prettyJsonString);

return prettyJsonString;
```

The other approach returns the same ugly output in browser, but it also adds "/r/n":

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String prettyJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(content);

return prettyJsonString;
```

Can anyone help me get the pretty output in browser as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in html with \`\n\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: I looked and the questions have nothing in common :(

Comment: @Maria1995 As far as I remember in broweser you should use JSON enhancer. In Chrome you can use JSON Viewer.

Comment: You can use a browser extension for pretty printing the JSON in the browser.

Comment: Have you tried putting in pretty JSON string inside a preformatted text tag? something like... `<pre> prettyJsonString here </pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Formatting String for console output and for HTML output are two VERY different tasks. Method `setPrettyPrinting()` is for console printing. HTML browser will ignore "\n" symbols and will not respect multiple spaces replacing them with a single space etc. In general, it is usually a client-side task to format the output. But I delt once with this problem and wrote a method that takes a console-formatted string and converts it to Html formatted String. For instance, it replaces all "\n" symbols with **br** Html tags. It does some other things as well. I had some success with it, but sometimes some unexpected problems occurred. You are welcome to use it. The method is available in MgntUtils Open source library. Here is its [JavaDoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml-java.lang.String-). The library itself is available as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and on Github (including source code and JavaDoc) [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). An article about the library is [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/michaelgantman/2016/01/26/open-source-java-library-with-stacktrace-filtering-silent-string-parsing-and-version-comparison). Your code would look like this:

```
String htmlString = TextUtils.formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml(jsonPrettyString);
```

Comment: Please, write here if it helped or not

Comment: I am glad to hear that, thank you. Consider accepting my answer then, please.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and stumbled upon how to get it to pretty print in the browser.
In your `application.properties` file, add these two lines:

```
# Preferred JSON mapper to use for HTTP message conversion.
spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson

# Whether to output serialized JSON that fits in a page for pretty printing.
spring.gson.pretty-printing=true
```

Reference: https://www.callicoder.com/configuring-spring-boot-to-use-gson-instead-of-jackson/
Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044963