# How do I get JSONObject as a StructuredArgument in a LogStashEncoder logback output?

Tags: java, json, logging, logback, structured-logging

I am using logback and `LogstashEncoder` to write JSON format logging to the console. I am using `StructuredArguments` to pass the objects I want in the log from my code to the logger. However my `JSONObject` is not appearing as a structured object in the JSON, although it appears in the log *message* OK.

Here is my simple code. Note `Order` is just a simple POJO with a single `orderId` field.

```
        Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("firstName", "Jane");

        JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject(user);
        
        Order order = new Order("123");

        logger.info("msg with one KV and 2 patterns {} {} {}"
            , StructuredArguments.keyValue("user", user)
            , StructuredArguments.keyValue("userDetails", userDetails)
            , StructuredArguments.keyValue("order", order)
            );
```

This produces the following JSON log message. I have removed some fields (log level, etc.) for brevity.

```
{
   "message":"msg with one KV and 2 patterns user={firstName=Jane} userDetails={\"firstName\":\"Jane\"} order=test.logging.JSONOutputExample$Order@3aa078fd",
   "level":"INFO",
   "user":{
      "firstName":"Jane"
   },
   "userDetails":{
   },
   "order":{
      "orderId":"123"
   }
}
```

You can see the `order` and `user` objects are nicely formatted in the both the message and the JSON object, however the `org.json.JSONObject` `userDetails` appears in the JSON log message but is *empty* in the full structured JSON log.

I am guessing this is perhaps something to do with a formatter or mapper? I assume `toString()` is used on the objects to get the inline `message` content (hence the `order` object is the fallback instance description - if I add a `toString()` to the `Order` object then I see that instead. However, for the structured JSON object something extra is going on as the `Order` is nicely converted to JSON, as is the `user` `HashMap`.

Here is my `logback.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And here is the dependencies in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

What am I missing? Is there a dependency missing that would map the `JSONObject` to actual JSON output? Should I do something different in the code to format it? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

===============================================================

**UPDATE**

I updated the *version* of the `org.json` dependency to `20230618` and now the `StructuredArgument` output for the `userDetails` is not longer empty, but of the form:

```
   "userDetails":{
      "empty":false,
      "mapType":"java.util.HashMap"
   }
```

Curious..?!? Obviously the 'standard' `toString()` type output or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution to my issue. The problem I had was in a Spring Boot application, and the above question was an attempt to distill a minimal example.

The problem is that I am using `org.json.JSONObject` and passing it to a `StructuredArgument`. When I enabled *debug* in the `logback.xml` configuration, like this ...

```
<configuration debug="true">
```

I get more output - including some errors from logback that caused log lines to not appear. From those errors I was lead to the question [Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169128/could-not-write-json-jsonobject-nested-exception-is-com-fasterxml-jackson-data) where the suggested solution was to enable the Spring property  `spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson`. I tried this, but it made no difference.
As I own the application, I changed the code to use Jackson JSON objects directly and then all was good.

So the top tip is ... if you have logback JSON logging issues, turn on logback *debug* to see if there are any problems 'hidden' from you.