# HTML not rendering new line characters properly?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, jupyter

I am trying to render the [following HTML](https://pastebin.com/0M4euacc). When I print it in Jupyter Notebooks, it works properly. [image]

But when I render the same html on Google, this is the result.

[image]

As we can see all the `\n` and even the `\t` characters are not being rendered correctly. How do I fix this?

The HTML can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/0M4euacc).

Here is a smaller reproducible example.

```
<div class=\"judgments\">\n<div class=\"docsource_main\">Madras High Court</div>\n<div class=\"doc_title\">K.Marappan vs The Deputy Registrar Of ... on 29 September, 2006</div><pre id=\"pre_1\">       \n\n  \n\n  \n\n \n \n IN THE HIGH COURT OF JUDICATURE AT MADRAS \n\nDATED:   29/09/2006 \n\nCORAM\n\nTHE HON\u0012BLE MR.AJIT PRAKASH SHAH, CHIEF JUSTICE\nTHE HON\u0012BLE MR. JUSTICE P.K.MISRA\nTHE HON\u0012BLE MR. JUSTICE D.MURUGESAN\nTHE HON\u0012BLE MRS. JUSTICE PRABHA SRIDEVAN\nTHE HON\u0012BLE MR. JUSTICE M.JAICHANDREN \n\n\nWrit Appeal No.1573 of 1998 \n---------- \n\nK.Marappan\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t..Appellant \n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tVs. \n\n1. The Deputy Registrar of Co-operative Societies,\n    Namakkal Circle,\n    Namakkal - 636 001. \n\n2. The Special Officer,\n    Vattur Co-operative Agricultural Bank,\n    Vattur Post,\n    Tiruchengode Taluk, \n    Salem District. \t\t\t\t\t         ..Respondents \n\n\nPRAYER: Appeal filed under Clause - 15 of the Letters Patent against \nthe order of the learned single passed in W.P.No.1245 of 1989 dated 12.02.1998. \n\n----------\n\t\tFor Appellant\t\t:: Mr.N.G.R.Prasad\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFor M/s.Row &amp; Reddy\n\n\t\tFor Respondent -1 \t:: Mr.R.Viduthalai, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tAdvocate General\n\t\t\t\t\t\tassisted by Mr.G.Sankaran, A.G.P.\n\n\t\tFor Respondent - 2 \t:: Mr.T.Senthilnathan \n\n-----------\n\t\t\t\t\t\nJ U D G M E N T \n</pre>\n<p id=\"p_1\">THE HON\u0012BLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE\n\nA five-Judge Bench of this Court in <a href=\"/doc/14026/\" id=\"a_1\">M.Thanikkachalam v. Madhuranthagam Agricultural Co-operative Society</a>, 2000 (4) CTC 556:2001 (1) LLJ 285, has held that no writ will lie against a co-operative society, since it is not an instrumentality of the \u0011State\u0012 within the meaning of <a href=\"/doc/609139/\" id=\"a_2\">Article 12</a> of the Constitution of India. \n</p>\n<p id=\"p_2\">\t2. While hearing the present writ appeal filed against the order of the learned single Judge dismissing the writ petition against a co-operative society, the Division Bench {Markandey Katju, C.J. (as he then was) and F.M.I.K.J.} doubting the five-Judge Bench decision, by order dated 9.8.2005, referred the following question to be decided by a Larger Bench.\n</p><p id=\"p_3\">\" Whether the decision of the five-Judge Bench of this Court in <a href=\"/doc/14026/\" id=\"a_3\">M.Thanikkachalam v. Madhuranthakam Agricultural Co-operative Society</a>, 2000 (4) CTC 556 : 2001 WLR 1, holding that no Writ will lie against a co-operative society is correct in law?\"\n</p>\n<p id=\"p_4\">Pursuant to the said order, the above question was referred to a Full Bench consisting of three Judges. The Full Bench took the view that it will be open only for a Bench of coequal strength to express an opinion doubting the correctness of the view taken by the earlier Bench of coequal strength, whereupon the matter may be placed for hearing before the Bench consisting of a quorum larger than the one which pronounced the decision laying down the law, the correctness of which is doubted. Consequently, the matter has been placed before this five-Judge Bench.\n</p>\n<p id=\"p_5\">3. Before considering the question referred to the Bench, it will be useful to refer to the decision of M.Thanikkachalam's case (cited supra).  It is seen from paragraph-11 of the aforesaid judgment that in view of difference of opinion, a Larger Bench was constituted to answer the question put forth as to whether the decision in R.Thamilarasan, etc. v. Director of Handlooms and Textiles, Madras and others, 1989 (1) LLJ 588, which got the seal of approval of two Full Benches of this Court required reconsideration.
```

Comment: How are you printing it on Jupyter Notebooks?  Are you trying to open the HTML on `Google Chrome`?  You may need to use the line break HTML tag <br/> for new lines.

Comment: Newlines don't break lines in html like they do with regular text. That's the job of the `<br>` element. There are ways to get around this with styling (e.g., a `<code>` element). See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Comment: Yes, this worked.