# `\n` not creating new lines inside <p> tag

Tags: html

I have a `<p>` with some large content in it. This is paragraph is retrieved from firebase realtime database. As we cannot store use `\n` directly in firebase database (because when retrieved it will simply print as \n in the paragraph).

So I store it in firebase database as `_n_` and when retrieved in my JavaScript code I replace it with `\n`. Just like below:

```
let formattedContent = String(content).replace(/_n_/g, "\n");
```

Content is just data received.

The `\n` is not working here. But when I change the tag from `<p>` to `<pre>` it worked. All the \n present were doing the job of adding new lines.

But some of my lines are pretty long and content will overflow the container if I use the pre tag.
Even though I have added word wrap. `word-wrap: break-word;`

So how can I get `\n` working in `<p>` tag?

**EDIT:** I have tried replacing with `<br/>` but it justs prints itself inside the P tag.
Also for some reason [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n) kept overflowing my container.

Comment: Replace `\n`s with `<br>`s, `\n` is not a part of HTML (excluding some special elements like `pre`), it's is renedered as it is.

Comment: @Teemu please check my EDIT part in question

Comment: Then we need to know how you're adding the string into the DOM.

Comment: how are you passing `formattedContent` to the content of the `<p>`?

Comment: @PedroLima `logContent.textContent = formattedContent;`

Comment: Use `.innerHTML` instead.

Comment: @Teemu check above comment. By the way `logContent` is name of P

Comment: You need to set `innerHTML`, or call [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: @PedroLima it did work

Comment: @Teemu innerHTML did it for me. Thanks. Didn't found that on SO anywhere

Comment: @appleapple w3school and also a reference video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: sorry I link to my local language :P here is the English link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: If you use `element.innerText`, `\n` will work.

Comment: @D.Pardal I'll try. I have user innerHTML for now

Comment: @appleapple no prob. I had changed that language :-)