# Environment.NewLine not breaking a string to next line

Tags: c#

I have the following code :

Model code :

```
public class StudentViewModel
{        
    public string FirstAddress { get; set; }
    public string SecondAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string FullAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecondAddress))
            {
                return $"{Address1}{Environment.NewLine}{Address2}{Environment.NewLine}{City}, {State} {Zipcode}";
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{Address1}{Environment.NewLine}{City}, {State} {Zipcode}";
            }
        }
        set { this.FullAddress = value; }
    }

}
```

This is how it's populated.

```
var record = context.StudentAdresses.Where(w => w.Active).Select(s => new {new StudentViewModel{FirstAddress =s.Address1, SecondAddress =s.Address2, City=s.City, State=s.State, Zipcode =s.Zipcode}).ToList();
```

View :

```
@model List<StudentViewModel>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                @foreach (var record in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           @record.FullAddress
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
             </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

But the Full name does not appear with new line. Instead I get a single line of Address.

```
410 Address1 City, CA 32130
```

where as I need:

```
410 Address1
City, CA 32130
```

Comment: it seems a simple `$"...\r\n..."` in your string will solve the problem.

Comment: Bear in mind that HTML ignores line breaks unless you explicitly add a `<br>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: @Progman white-space: pre-line while works fine with my string; adds an extra blank line at the top.

Comment: @Powerlord so do you mean I need to add <br> in the view and can't do anything in my model?

Comment: Btw, the `set`ter of your property is recursive and will cause a Stackoverflow if you ever tried to use it. I would think that it should not even exist since the `get`ter is calculated from other properties

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is from @Powerlord above. Html does replace newlines by a simple whitespace. So you need to replace newline with the html `<br />` tag to enforce a line break. That comment should be the right answer

Comment: so do you mean I need to add <br> in the view and can't do anything in my model on the server side?

Comment: @TheFallenOne: No you don't have to do so but I would. I think the presentation of data is the job of the view and not of the model. I would pass an address object to the view and do the formatting there.

Answer (score -1):

it is work for me

change lie below:

add br tag before {City}

```
  return $"{Address1}{Environment.NewLine}{"<br/>"}{City}, {State} {Zipcode}";
```

in razor page :

```
   @Html.Raw(@record.FullAddress)
```

Comment: Not a solution. _Environment.Newline_ does just that in a platform independent manner. Inserting just "\n" is wrong on Microsoft systems. So the code of the OP is error free while you introduced bad code and did not solve the problem at all

Comment: check I changed . @TheFallenOne

Comment: please check... i changed  it is work for me @TheFallenOne