# Javascript adding newline with backtick syntax

Tags: javascript, newline

I'm trying to format some text with newlines using the backtick syntax like so:

```
text: `Foo
        Bar` 
  },
```

https://codepen.io/nz2198/pen/eYpoRdw?editable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fsweetalert2.github.io%2F

The text isn't getting delimitited by a newline. How do I fix this?

Comment: It actually is indented; check the innerHTML of `#swal2-content` element. But whitespace is collapsed by default when displaying non-preformatted element.

Comment: Check this thread for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your text as HTML, as the doc says : https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration

Following your current codepen link, you just have to replace "text" with "html" :

```
{
    title: 'Question 1',
    html: 'Foo <br\>Bar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a property to the css class. it should make the whitespace render as you want.

```
.swal2-html-container {
    white-space: pre;
}
```