# ( Laravel ) Break lines not working ; Balise aren't displayed anymore but it won't start a new line

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to break a line but it's always displayed whatever I do so I guess I'm doing something wrong.
[Here is my line from my php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLaeI.png)

But it's displayed like this :

`My site is designed to help content creators on the web, create a free account and start \nmaking money now.`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: `\n` only turns into a newline for strings using  `"`. For example: `"This has a newline at the end.\n"` and `'This doesn't have a newline at the end.\n'`.

Comment: Okay I did this and the balise isn't displayed anymore but it's not starting a new line. The line just continue as if there was no \n .

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `\n` with a `<br>` tag? `{!! !!}` does not escape html, so that will force a line break.

Comment: Actually ```\n``` disappeared but ```{!! !!}``` are still displayed

Comment: The `{!! !!}` would be used when displaying the variable on the page (assuming this is in a blade file), not as part of the string.  (e.g., `{!! $subtitle_welcome !!}`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `\n` with `<br>`
2. Use `<p></p>`

   My site is designed to help content creators on the web, create a free account and start

   making money now
3. Use CSS `white-space` property for `\n` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178556/4721265))

Comment: Hmm, it's solved my whole day's problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<br>` on blade, and if you use `{!! !!}` i think that must be inner html inside your string. cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

You can save your html text as variable like this

```
$subtitle_welcome = "<p>My site is designed to help content creators on the web, create a free account and start </p> <p> making money now.</p>";
```

OR

```
$subtitle_welcome = "My site is designed to help content creators on the web, create a free account and start <br/> making money now.";
```

And you have to show in blade

```
{!! $subtitle_welcome !!}
```