# display string on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to display my string on multiple lines. I already tried something like `replaceAll(",", "\n")`
Here's my Code:

```
<template>
    <v-form>
        <v-container>
          <v-card
              class="mt-15 pa-4  mx-auto"
              max-width="1000"
              multi-line>
            {{consoleOutput.toString().replaceAll(",", "\n")}}
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            consoleOutput: ["This", "should", "be", "on a ", "new Line "],
        })
    }
</script>
```

I get this output `This should be on a new Line`. My target is to print each string on a different line and add a index in front of it (equal to console) like:

```
1. This
2. should
3. be 
4. on a 
5. new Line
```

Comment: either add a <br> after each line of use <pre>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: Why don't you use a <template></template> and loop over consoleOutput, using for example a <p> tag for each string ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `ol` element and `v-for` to render each `li`

```
 <v-card
    class="mt-15 pa-4  mx-auto"
    max-width="1000"
    multi-line
>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="item in consoleOutput" :key="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ol>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this.

```
 <v-container>
  <v-card
      class="mt-15 pa-4  mx-auto"
      max-width="1000"
      multi-line>
      <div v-for="item in consoleOutput.toString().split(',')" :key="item">        
        {{item}}
      </div>
  </v-card>
</v-container>
```

Please confirm this URL.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gmadqd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue