# Javascript Linebreaks: See raw textfield data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-blade

If I enter in Textfield some characters including whitespaces, I want to adapt it to the table:

```
alert(office.contact)
```

[image]

Unfortunate, the line breaks aren't adapted, when field is updated

```
<td>{!! nl2br(e($Office->contact)) !!}</td>
```

[image]

How can I read out the raw data (incl. Linebreaks) in office.contact?

Expected outcome (office.contact):

```
<td> Line 1 <br>
     Line 2 <br>
     Line n
</td>
```

Thank you very much
Carlson

Comment: Line breaks in HTML need to be rendered as the break element `<br>`. Alternatively you can render the text inside a `<pre>` element which will preserve the whitespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: Hi, I want the opposite of preseve. In Alert the text is shown correctly with new Lines (<br>). But as soon I render, new lines are preserved.

Comment: You need to render the newlines as `<br>`. Please check the question linked in my previous comment.

Comment: See [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNZyPrL)