# How add a new line with (</br>) in vue js data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

here is the code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Add A Review</p>
    <input
      v-model="test"
      type="text"
    >
    <button @click="showRev()">
      Add
    </button>
    <p>Your Review : {{ res }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        test: '',
        res: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      showRev () {
        this.res += this.test + '<br/>'
      },
    },
  }
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: [The `br` element's](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) tag omission rules are "No end tag." **not** "No start tag.". This means `</br>` is wrong and `<br>` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mustache operator (shorthand syntax for `v-text` directive) only prints strings, or call the default `toString()` method for objects.

So here it will print `'</br>'` as a string and not compile it as HTML.

If you need this, you can use the `v-html` directive ([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)), to make vue understand you want it to render the parameter as HTML.

```html
<template>
  <p>Your Review : <span v-html="res" /> </p>
</template>
```

---

Note: but if you only need to add a line return after your text, I suggest you to read this thread about new lines in HTML: [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)