# Newline is being ignored

Tags: html

I'm currently working on a fairly simplistic error handling system, but it seems my attempt to add newlines is being ignored.

Expected behaviour:

```
[expression]: errormessage
[expression2]: errormessage2
[expression2]: errormessage3
```

etc

Current behaviour: `[expression]: errormessage [expression2]: errormessage2 [expression2]: errormessage3`

Im building my string like this:

```
    result.map((errorObject) => {
      errorMessage = `${errorMessage} ${errorObject.error}` + "\n";
    });
```

I have also tried:

```
    result.map((errorObject) => {
      errorMessage = `${errorMessage} ${errorObject.error}\n`;
    });
```

After the result.map has finished i return the errorMessage object to my React component for rendering. This component is a simple html p object.

```
  {validationMessage && validationError && (
    <ErrorMessage>{validationMessage}</ErrorMessage>
  )}
```

console logs of validationMessage returns:

```
validationMessage: " [expression]: errormessage\n [epression2] errormessage2\n [expression3]: errormessage3\n"}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. If more information is needed please feel free to ask and i will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Nothing to do with React. Nothing to do with JavaScript. HTML ignores newlines. It always has. You should either use `<br>` tags for newlines, or add them as them as separate elements (e.g., `<p>` tag for each line) or use a CSS rule to force new lines to show up.

Comment: @VLAZ Incorrect tags and title [tags] removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ignores newlines. So instead of trying to map the data and create newlines like that, you should implement it on a component level, how the data is displayed.

You can use [p](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp) tags (paragraphs) or [br](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) (breaks) to create new lines. You may also want to look around here for solutions: [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: Much appreciated. Helpful response that solved my issue.

Comment: Happy to help! :)