# New line characters not displaying as new line on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I retrieve alert messages from an API and join using the `\r\n` method. It is joining correctly and logging correctly to the console, however it is not displaying the alerts on a new line. It instead just ignores those characters and goes on to the next part of the string.

Example:

```
//Thunk
if (warningResults && warningResults.length) {
          dispatch(
            upsertAppNotification(
              AppNotificationsCenter.getNotificationByKey(
                NotificationKeys.CustomerAlertWarning,
                warningResults.join('\r\n')
              ),
              0
            )
          );
        }
```

I log the notification to the console and it shows like this:

```
Message: "Warning Message One\r\nWarning Message Two,
```

But it displays on the page like this: [image]

Here's the code that displays the message:

```
{props.message && (
                <StyledTextBox data-testid={props.messageTestId} maxWidth="80%">
                  <Typography variant="paragraph">{props.message}</Typography>
                </StyledTextBox>
              )}
```

Comment: HTML doesn't respect `\r` you'll need to use the [line break element (`<br>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) - Or use a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Comment: <br> does not work either

Comment: It will work, but without you showing why your effort doesn't, we cannot help. (Do not post code in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text with `pre` tag

```
<pre>
   {message}
</pre>
```

or add this style: `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: sx={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}} worked for me, thanks