# how to handle line breaks with django and js

Tags: javascript, django

I store in my db.sqlite3 of django some patterns which can contain a line break (\n). On the /admin page you can still see them. But when I load the content now into the frontend, this is written in a line.
But if I output the sentence in the console, I get the line break

The following record is stored in the Django database as follows:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

```
<div id=response_1>

</div>


document.getElementById('response_1').innerHTML = responses[0] //Hello World

console.log(responses[0]) // Hello
                             World
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: Yes this helped. But I also need to know how I get the text with the '\n'. So without the automatically reformatting it to a new line