# New line in MudToolTip text

Tags: c#, mudblazor

Please guide how to add line break in MudToolTip text. I have a string variable toolTipText in my MudBlazor application. This variable is used as Text in MudTooltip. I want adding System.Environment.NewLine as two lines separator, but it does not effect and tooltip shows only one line. My code is as below:

[image: Sample Code]

"Line 1 text" and "Line 2 text" are shown together on one line.

Comment: Have you tried `<br>` instead of `System.Environment.NewLine`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing a string as text, you can also [embed HTML in your tooltip](https://mudblazor.com/components/tooltip#html-tooltips):

```html
<MudTooltip>
    <ChildContent>
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Filled.Info" />
    </ChildContent>
    <TooltipContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Line 1 text</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Line 2 text</MudText>
    </TooltipContent>
</MudTooltip>
```

Try online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQQPYbhQmuAymWu

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: pre-line;`. Add this class to your `app.css` file:

```css
.white-space-pre-line {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

And add it to the tooltip:

```
<MudTooltip Text="@tooltipText" Class="white-space-pre-line" ...>
    ...
</MudTooltip>
```

Check: [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)