# angular make data shows as format in single blind

Tags: html, json, angular

There is test data shows on frontend

```
{"id" : "49", "users" : {"type" : "test"}}
```

and at angular html file, test is list which get from api service call

```
get().subscribe((resp)=>{
  this.test = resp["data"];
})
```

```
<td>{{test.name}}</td>
<td>{{test.json}}</td>
```

what i am want is make test shows as format

```
{
 "id" : "49", 
 "users" : {"type" : "test"}
}
```

I tried add {{test.json|json}} use json pipe, but html shows
"{\r\n\r\n}"

also I add parseJson at component, {{parseJson(test.json)}}, html get [object Object]

```
parseJson(str:string):any{
   return JSON.parse(str);
 }
```

because of "\r\n", I tried {{parseJson(test.json)}}

```
 parseJson(str:string):any{
    console.log(str);
    console.log(str.includes("\r\n")); // it's true
}
```

html at console shows

```
{
 "id" : "49", 
 "users" : {"type" : "test"}
}
```

but do not have line break at html for

```
<td>{{parseJson(test.json)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's format at console, at last I add css style to  white-space: pre-line;
[Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Answer (score 0):

To format JSON on an HTML page you can make use of the [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe). You can also wrap it in a `pre` tag to maintain the correct formatting. Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4buhq?file=src/main.ts) showing how it works.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>JSON Formatting</h1>
    <pre>
{{jsonData | json}}
    </pre>
  `,
})
export class App {
  jsonData = { id: '49', users: { type: 'test' } };
}
```

Comment: Hello, when I add  {{test.testJSON | json}} , the html shows as ```"{\r\n \"id\" : \"80\",\r\n \"amount\" : \"120\",\r\n \}" ```