# How can I add new line in JS? \n not working

Tags: javascript, string

I am learning/refreshing/playing with data. In this example, I am looking for even and odd length string in sentence. But character for new line is not working.
Can you show me what am I doing wrong? THANK YOU.

```
const evenOddLength = (t: string) => {
     let text = strings.split(' ')
      const even: string [] = []
     const odd: string [] = []

     for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if(text[i].length % 2 === 0) {
         even.push(text[i])
      } else {
        odd.push(text[i])
      }
     }

    setOutput(`Even string: [ ${even} ],` + "\n" + ` Odd string: [ ${odd} ]`) 

  }
```

Expected output should be:

```
Even string: [ String,be,iterated,loop ],
Odd string: [ The,Array,can,using,the,for ]

but I am getting :

Even string: [ String,be,iterated,loop ], Odd string: [ The,Array,can,using,the,for ]
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `setOutput` function? Maybe that's where the problem is  Also, on an unrelated note, you can probably use `Even string: [ ${even} ],\n Odd string: [ ${odd} ]` which is cleaner :)

Comment: const [output, setOutput] = useState<number | string>()

Comment: it is useState() , in div is:   <p className='text-center my-5'>{output}</p>

Comment: Wait, I see the problem.

Comment: I am learning typescript and with that refreshing data modeling. :)

Comment: Actually, I don't think I see it... Sorry haha

Comment: HTML doesn't render `\n`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Answer (score 0):

To do a line break in HTML, you should use the `<br>` tag instead of `\n`

```js
let even = [];
let odd = [];
function evenOddLength(t) { 
   let text = t.split(' ');

   for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if(text[i].length % 2 === 0) {
        even.push(text[i]);
      } else {
        odd.push(text[i]);
      }
   } 
} 

evenOddLength('The Array can using the for String be iterated loop');
document.getElementById("useJsNewLine").innerHTML = `* Using Javascript line break (\\n): Even string: [ ${even} ],` + "\n" + ` Odd string: [ ${odd} ]`;
document.getElementById("useHtmlBrTag").innerHTML = `* Using HTML line break (br tag):<br/>Even string: [ ${even} ],` + "<br/>" + ` Odd string: [ ${odd} ]`;
```

```html
<p id="useJsNewLine">Using Javascript line break (\n):</p>
<p id="useHtmlBrTag">Using HTML line break (br tag):</p>
```