# Django Email doesn't render HTML tags

Tags: python, django, email, html-email

I am trying to make an email notification system using Django, but there's a problem. The body of the email doesn't render html tags, and instead the body display the html tag and the message in a long line instead. Even when the message contains \n, it doesn't create a new line but the \n is not visible in the body of the email

This is my email template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{subject}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{body}}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code to send the email

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from django.conf import settings

class SendNotification:
    @staticmethod
    def by_email(instance):
        subject = instance.subject
        to = list(instance.receivers.values_list("to", flat=True))
        html_content = render_to_string("email.html", {'subject': subject, "body": instance.message})
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        try:
            email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject,
                text_content,
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                to,
            )
            email.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
            email.send()

            instance.counter += 1
            instance.save()
            instance.receivers.all().update(status=True)
```

any idea why the html tag is not rendered properly?

Answer (score 1):

AKX's last point is the correct answer as I interpret your question.

If body has HTML in it you need to include it into the template as `{{body | safe}}`, otherwise Django will replace your < with `&lt;` and so on.

Safe is indicating "this content is safe to render, I know what I'm doing" where as the default is "unsafe", meaning that any <, > and a few other odds and ends will be escaped as they might be user provided content that leads to XSS attacks (see https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

If it's just being viewed as email the risks are less than in a browser, but it's worth considering all of the sources of data for the email template and where erroneous or malicious input might be introduced.

Not to do with your question but depending on the audience you might want to consider bcc rather than to as well, and the `Precedence: Bulk` header can be handy to stop getting a bunch of out-of-office emails in reply to your messages (potentially causing a big ol' email loop).

Answer (score 0):

[Same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39325414/51685) why the following snippet says "hello world" on one line.

```html
<div>
hello

world
</div>
```

Use Django's [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) filter to add `<br>` tags where newlines are, i.e. `{{ body | linebreaksbr }}`

and you'll end up with

```html
<div>
hello<br>
<br>
world
</div>
```

On the other hand, if your `body` already has HTML tags itself, you'll need to mark it with the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter.